# Javascript help using helper function random button to display 1 of 5 different input boxes?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create 1 set of 5 input boxes using a submit button to produce the results the producing a random mad lib.

1. create a submit button when clicked randomly chooses a number which runs a mad lib
2. without changing page creates the boxes according to mad lib
3. then gets the user input to then
4. prints out mad lib

.is

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",init);
function init(){
var randomButton = document.createElement('button');
randomButton.innerHTML ="random";
randomButton.addEventListener("click", random);
document.getElementById("displayArea");
}
function random(){
var randomNumber = Math.random();
randomNumber *= 10;
randomNumber = Math.floor(randomNumber);
randomNumber = randomNumber % 7;
console.log(randomNumber);
if(randomNumber==1){
    var userDataObject = buildingMadLib0();
    var madLib0 = madLib0(userDataObject);
    var displayArea = document.getElementById("madlib0");
    displayArea.innerHTML = madLid0;
}else if(randomNumber==2){
    var userDataObject = buildingMadLib1();
    var madLib1 = madLib1(userDataObject);
    var displayArea = document.getElementById("madlib1");
    displayArea.innerHTML = madLid1;
}else if(randomNumber==3){
    var userDataObject = buildingMadLib2();
    var madLib2 = madLib2(userDataObject);
    var displayArea = document.getElementById("madlib2");
    displayArea.innerHTML = madLid2;
}else if(randomNumber==4){
    var userDataObject = buildingMadLib3();
    var madLib3 = madLib1(userDataObject);
    var displayArea = document.getElementById("madlib3");
    displayArea.innerHTML = madLid3;
}else if(randomNumber==5){
    var userDataObject = buildingMadLib4();
    var madLib4 = madLib4(userDataObject);
    var displayArea = document.getElementById("madlib4");
    displayArea.innerHTML = madLid4;
    }
  }
//sfunction formSubmitted(){
//}
function buildingMadLib0(){
var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun,"Noun");
var noun = document.getElementById("noun1").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun1,"Noun");
var noun = document.getElementById("noun2").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun2,"Noun");
var place = document.getElementById("place").value;
checkInputWithWarning(place,"Place");
var adjective = document.getElementById("adjective").value;
checkInputWithWarning(adjective,"Adjective");
var noun = document.getElementById("noun3").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun3,"Noun");
var madLibOneObjects = {noun:noun,
noun1:noun1,
    noun2:noun2,
    place:place,
    adjective:adjective,
    noun3:noun3};
return madLibOneObjects;
}
function buildingMadLib1(){

 var adjective = document.getElementById("adjective").value;
 checkInputWithWarning(adjective,"Adjective");
 var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;
 checkInputWithWarning(noun,"Noun");
 var animal = document.getElementById("animal").value;
 checkInputWithWarning(aniaml,"Animal");
 var noise = document.getElementById("noise").value;
 checkInputWithWarning(noise,"Noise");

 var madLibTwoObjects = { adjective:adjective,
    noun:noun,
    animal:animal,
     noise:noise,};

 return madLibTwoObjects;


 }

 function buildingMadLib2(){
 var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;
 checkInputWithWarning(noun,"Noun");
 var verb = document.getElementById("verb").value;
 checkInputWithWarning(verb,"Verb");
 var noun = document.getElementById("noun1").value;
 checkInputWithWarning(noun1,"Noun");
 var adjective = document.getElementById("adjective").value;
 checkInputWithWarning(adjective,"Adjective");

 var madLibThreeObjects = { noun:noun,
    verb:verb,
    noun1:noun1,
    adjective:adjective};

 return madLibThreeOjects;


 }

function buildingMadLib3(){

var noun = document.getElementById("noun1").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun1,"Noun");
var verb = document.getElementById("verb").value;
checkInputWithWarning(verb,"Verb");
var noun = document.getElementById("noun2").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun2,"Noun");
var pronoun = document.getElementById("pronoun").value;
checkInputWithWarning(pronoun,"Pronoun");
var noun = document.getElementById("noun3").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun3,"Noun");
var pronoun = document.getElementById("pronoun1").value;
checkInputWithWarning(pronoun1,"Pronoun");
var verb = document.getElementById("verb2").value;
checkInputWithWarning(verb2,"Verb");

var madLibFourObjects = {noun1:noun1,
verb:verb,
noun2:noun2,
pronoun:pronoun,
noun3:noun3,
pronoun1:pronoun1,
    verb2:verb2};

return madLibFourObjects;
}
function buildingMadLib4(){

var verb = document.getElementById("verb").value;
checkInputWithWarning(verb,"Verb");
var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun,"Noun");
var noun = document.getElementById("noun1").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun1,"Noun");
var noun = document.getElementById("noun2").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun2,"Noun");
var noun = document.getElementById("noun3").value;
checkInputWithWarning(noun3,"Noun");

var madLibFiveObjects = {verb:verb,
noun:noun,
noun1:noun1,
noun2:noun2,
noun3:noun3};

return madLibFiveObjects;
}

function madLib0(userDataObject){

var madLib0 = "Be kind to your "+ userDataObject.noun + "footed "+  userDataObject.noun ;
 madLib0 += "For a duck may be somebody`s" +userDataObject.noun + ", ";
 madLib0 += "Be kind to your in " + userDataObject.place;
 madLib0 += "Where the weather is always " + userDataObject.adjective;
 madLib0 += "You may think that this is the" + userDataObject.noun + " ,";
 madLib0 += "Well it is.";
                                               }


 function madLib1(userDataObject){
 var madLib1 = userDataObject.adjective + "MAcdonald had a "+ userDataObject.noun + ", E-I-E-I-O";
madLib1 += "and on that he had an "+ userDataObject.animal +",E-I-E-I O";
madLib1 += "with a" + userDataObject.noise +" here";
madLib1 += "and a there,";
madLib1 += "here a, there a,";
madLib1 += "everywhere a,";
madLib1 += "Macdonald had a, E-I-E-I-O";
                                               }

function madLib2(userDataObject){

var mabLib2 = "There are to many "+ userDataObject.noun + userDataObject.verb;
madLib2 += userDataObject.noun +"on this " + userDataObject.adjective;
madLib2 += "plane! He screamed.";
                                               }
 function madLib3(userDataObject){
 var madLib3 = "one day " +userDataObject.noun;
 madLib3 += "was "+ userDataObject.verb +" to the";
 madLib3 += userDataObject.noun + " on the way.";
 madLib3 += userDataObject.pronoun +" saw a " + userDataObject.noun;
 madLib3 += "This was a suprise";
 madLid3 += "so "+ userDataObject.pronoun + userDataObject.verb +" quickly.";
                                               }
function madLib4(userDataObject){

 var madLib4 = "mothers sit around "+userDataObject.verb+", last";
 madLib4 += "summer, my little brother fell i a " +userDataObject.noun+" and got";
 madlib4 += "poisen "+ userDataObject.noun +" all over his " + userDataObject.noun;
 madLib4 += "my family is going to "+ userDataObject.noun + ".";
                                               }

<html>

<title>MadLib</title>
<script src="MadLib.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><div>Click Submit to randomly get a Mad Lib!!!</div></p>
    <p><button id="random">Submit</button></p>
    <div id="displayArea"></div>
    <fieldset id="madlib0">
        Noun: <input id="noun" type="text">
            Noun: <input id="noun1" type="text">
                Noun: <input id="noun2" type="text">
                    Place: <input id="place" type="text">
                        Adjective: <input id="adjective" type="text">
                            Noun: <input id="noun3" type="text">
                                <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="madlib1">
        Adjective:<input id="adjective" type="text">
            Noun:<input id="noun" type="text">
                Animal:<input id="animal" type="text">
                    Noise:<input id="noise" type="text">
                        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="madlib2">
        Noun:<input id="noun" type="text">
            Verb:<input id="verb" type="text">
                Noun:<input id="noun" type="text">
                    Adjective:<input id="adjective" type="text">
                        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="madlib3">
        Noun:<input id="noun1" type="text">
            Verb:<input id="verb" type="text">
                Noun:<input id="noun2" type="text">
                    Pronoun:<input id="pronoun" type="text">
                        Noun:<input id="noun3" type="text">
                            Pronoun:<input id="pronoun1" type="text">
                            Verb:<input id="verb2" type="text">
                                <button id="submit">Submit</button>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="madlib4">
        Verb:<input id="verb" type="text">
            Noun:<input id="noun" type="text">
                Noun:<input id="noun1" type="text">
                    Noun:<input id="noun2" type="text">
                        Noun:<input id="noun3" type="text">
                            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you write this, or are you trying to modify someone else's code? `randomButton` is created but not inserted into the HTML. Perhaps you wanted to set `randomButton` to the exisiting `button` that has `id="random"`? Also, `checkInputWithWarning` appears throughout the script but it is not defined anywhere.

Comment: no this is my own code. checkInputWithWarning is to make sure user inputs into the fieldset. i am struggling on creating the randomButton to random the field set

Answer (score 0):

The second line of your HTML `body` is

```
<p><button id="random">Submit</button></p>
```

If that's the button you want to use to invoke your `random()` function, you should change the line where you assign `var randomButton` to this:

```
var randomButton = document.getElementById('random');
```